# How to sort a rails 4 datetime column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm a bit confused about how to sort something. I am actually not even sure to begin. Should I put my sorting code in my model with a scope or should I just put it in the controller.

I have a list of school class periods. I would Like to sort this list first by the most recent date first, followed by the time the class begins. I have figured out how to sort other columns alphabetically and the start-time by using:

> Appointment.order("start")

However when I use this code, it IS sorting it, just not how I expect it would. The months are not in a chronological order and neither are the times. So why is it rearranging the data? How can I sort this column properly?

Comment: What datatype is your `start` column in the database?

Comment: start is a datetime column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to put your sorting logic in the `model` as a default scope for the ones that you use a lot like sorting by `created_at`:

```
default_scope {order('created_at DESC')}
```

for your case try this if it's in a reverse order:

```
Appointment.order(start: :desc)
```

I hope this was useful.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using default_scope: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/ Sort it in the controller method.

Comment: @devmarwen, Thanks, but this is actually my confusion. Well. actually im not sure if I am doing it right also... The 1st code is a scope that goes into my model, and the second code is code that goes into my controller, right? Assuming I inserted the code properly, it DOES sort my dates. However there are still inconsistencies with how it is ordering the 'start' datetimes. It seems to be sorting it by something else OTHER than the time or the actual months regardless if I sort by ASC or DESC.

Comment: @JoséToy well when you runnig your query look at your server logs and take a look at the sql query that get executed, this maybe will give you the reason. @CoderDave Thanks for your point , but I think that something as simple as `order(created_at: :desc)` will not affect the created records if it was put on a `default_scope`

Comment: That's a good point, I don't know why I didn't check that more thoroughly. I probably should have been more thoughtful and approached that earlier/more frequently. Anyways, your right, its not sorting by the start time the SQL in my terminal says:  

 User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 358143215]]
  Appointment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "appointments".* FROM "appointments"  ORDER BY starts_at DESC.     

So this means its sorting it by id then? but why does it say order by DESC and the end of the queries?

Comment: I re-entered my fixtures info to read:  2015-02-25 17:30:00. Originally it was written ' February-16-2015 09:30'. It seems to be sorting it properly by date and year but the time is still not a factor in the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it. Im not exactly sure what was wrong...

Could it be with how I loaded in my test fixtures? I originally had:

```
February-16-2015 09:30
```

and I changed it to this:

```
2015-02-25 17:30:00
```

Could this time format be the problem?

Comment: Did you ever verify if that was the issue? I am having the same thought...